# Importing and Sorting Text Files in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, import

I currently have a macro set up that allows me to paste data into column A from Textpad and then sorts, rounds, moves and saves the data as a txt file.

Is there anyway that I can modify the macro to allow me to import the txt file straight into Excel rather than having to copy and paste? The file names changes each time, but the file directory will stay the same.

This is the current macro I have that is run after manually copy and pasting the data into excel:

```
    'Sub SortRoundandSave()
    '
    ' SortTruncateandSave Macro
    ' This macro will sort, round and save your data
    '

    '
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("A:A,B:B,D:D").Select
Range("D1").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Truncated Data").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Truncated Data").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Truncated Data").Move
ChDir "G:\XXXX\Folder\Name\ZZZZ\Sort"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\XXXX\Folder\Name\ZZZZ\Sort\Sorted Data.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
Windows("Excel Truncator.xlsm").Activate
    End Sub
```

I assume it needs a few lines before the text to columns part, but I cant seem to get one to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub SortRoundandSave()
    '
    ' SortTruncateandSave Macro
    ' This macro will sort, round and save your data
    '
    Dim workSht As Worksheet: Set workSht = ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("") ' Enter the name of sheet

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim rowCnt As Long

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select the file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add Description:="Text Files", Extensions:="*.txt"
        '.InitialFileName = "G:\XXXX\Folder\Name" ' Optional: this is a startup directory, place the correct one and uncomment line
        If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
        FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    rowCnt = 1

    Open FilePath For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strLine
            workSht.Cells(rowCnt, 1) = strLine
            rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
        Loop
    Close #1


    With workSht
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowCnt - 1, 1)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
                                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                                :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        .Cells(1, 4).AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(workSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 4)) ' "D1:D" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 4)).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Truncated Data").Cells(1, 1)
    End With

    Sheets("Truncated Data").Move

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\XXXX\Folder\Name\ZZZZ\Sort\Sorted Data.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    workSht.Parent.Activate

End Sub
```